# Deleted MacOS partitions and installed Ubuntu, now can't boot with DVD, USB or internet recovery to reinstall MacOS

Tags: startup, install, partition, recovery, internet-recovery

I deleted all partitions on the MacBook's HD and installed Ubuntu.
Now I want to reinstall MacOS but nothing will work.

Holding <kbd>option</kbd> on startup shows the grey screen with the pointer but no removable media or HD partitions show up to boot from.

Holding <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at startup for recovery mode will just boot regularly into ubuntu.

Holding <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at startup for internet recovery will boot on Grub, Ubuntu's boot loader.

How can I reinstall MacOS in this situation?
Is there any other kind of low-level reset or something else that will let me boot from a DVD or USB device?
Is there a way to access something like the setup you get to by holding F2 on regular PCs?

Comment: Thanks for the help @user3439894, I used google, I saw all the pages you cited and more, do have another mac, did create bootable installers, did try to use the original install DVDs.
If you read my question you'll see that the start up manager won't show any partition or drive to boot from, and none of the recovery startup methods work, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Late 2009 Macbook.
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp579

Comment: Also, there are no Apple stores in my city, there are Apple repair services but as this is an old computer, I wouldn't spend a dime on it, I'm just trying to make it into a usable backup machine.

Comment: @user3439894 yes it does, I've used it already.

Comment: You said you have Late 2009 Macbook and according to [Computers that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313) the MacBook 13-inch, Mid 2010 is oldest to support it with a firmware update, but if you have then use it!

Comment: @user3439894 thanks, but as I wrote: "Holding option-command-R at startup for internet recovery will boot on Grub, Ubuntu's boot loader."
So internet recovery doesn't work.
It used to work, but not anymore since I wiped all MacOS partitions and installed Ubuntu.